# "Object scalatest is not a member of package org" where is the directory?

Tags: scala

I've seen my people stuck on this problem. And so as I. And many people said using sbt. And currently I've already downloaded sbt. But I don't know where the directories are, such as dir "/src/main/scala" or dir 
"/src/test/scala", could anybody tell me where are the directories? Thanks

Comment: Make sure to have the proper dependency defined in your build, otherwise there is no way for the compiler to find the corresponding package.

Answer (score 0):

- [Install](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Setup.html) sbt
- Use `sbt new`  [to create the default structure](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Hello.html)
- Add your dependencies (e.g. scalatest) and settings to build.sbt
- Copy your source files in the corresponding folders (src/main/scala, ...)
- Run sbt